# Python(Server) receiving Data from Java(client) In separate lines.. (TCP)

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

Okay so I read many questions and couldn't figure it out. I am facing problem with the data which I receive from my Android App. Basically I want to control a servo. The code works, but the data sent by the app to the server is received in separate lines. Yes i know i need to use buffer, I researched a bit but couldn't find a way to add a buffer to my code.
Also I don't think I need to show my Java Code because its just basic Commands (Strings like Up, Down, etc) Sending from the Button Clicks.

```
...Python Code(Server)...
  ctrCmd = ['Up','Down', 'ON', 'OFF']
  ...
  ...
  while True:
        print ("Waiting for connection")
        tcpCliSock,addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        print ("...connected from :", addr)

    try:
            while True:
                    data = ''
                    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE).decode()
                    print("This",data)

                    if not data:
                            print ("No Data",data)
                            break
                    if data == ctrCmd[0]:
                            print("I am here")
                            Servomotor.ServoUp()
                            print ("Increase: ",Servomotor.cur_X)
                            #tcpCliSock.send("Servo Increases".encode())
                    if data == ctrCmd[1]:
                            Servomotor.ServoDown()
                            print ("Decrease: ",Servomotor.cur_X)
                            #tcpCliSock.send("Servo Decreases".encode())
                    if data == ctrCmd[2]:
                            Servomotor.ledOn()
                            print ("Led On")
                            #tcpCliSock.send("Led On".encode())
                    if data == ctrCmd[3]:
                            Servomotor.ledOff()
                            print ("Led Off")
                           # tcpCliSock.send("Led Off".encode())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            Servomotor.close()
            GPIO.cleanup()
tcpSerSock.close();
```

[image]

Also i dont understand why it says No data even when it shows recieved data?
Please Help I'm really a noob and am trying to learn. 
THANKS!!

UPDATE!!
After I changed the decode() Suggested,

[image]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //UI Element
    Button btnUp;
    Button btnDown;
    Button btnLedOn;
    Button btnLedOff;
    EditText txtAddress;
    /*TextView message;*/
    Socket myAppSocket = null;
    public static String wifiModuleIp = "";
    public static int wifiModulePort = 0;
    public static String CMD = "0";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        btnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        btnLedOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLedOn);
        btnLedOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLedOff);
        txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress);
        /*message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);*/

        btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();
                CMD = "Up";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });
        btnDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();
                CMD = "Down";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });
        btnLedOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();;
                CMD = "ON";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_led_on = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_led_on.execute();
            }
        });
        btnLedOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();
                CMD = "OFF";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_led_off = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_led_off.execute();
            }
        });

    }
    public void getIPandPort()
    {
        String iPandPort = txtAddress.getText().toString();

        Log.d("MYTEST","IP String: "+ iPandPort);
        String temp[]= iPandPort.split(":");
        wifiModuleIp = temp[0];
        wifiModulePort = Integer.valueOf(temp[1]);
        Log.d("MY TEST","IP:" +wifiModuleIp);
        Log.d("MY TEST","PORT:"+wifiModulePort);
    }
    public class Socket_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        Socket socket;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

            try{

                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.wifiModuleIp);
                socket = new java.net.Socket(inetAddress,MainActivity.wifiModulePort);
                //read input msg from server

                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(CMD);
                System.out.println(CMD);
                dataOutputStream.close();

                socket.close();
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace();}catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the Android Code
[image]

UPDATED 17May
I tried writeUTF it gives some null data before Up(See Image)
[image]

Comment: Hello, what is your buffer size?

Comment: Hey!..It is 1024

Comment: And if you try increasing your buffer size to 2048?

Comment: yes I did that, still the same thing, This same code worked well when I wrote it back in python 2, but after python 3 or what happened its giving this sort of out put, It gives proper output if I Click on the 'Up' Button on My Android app 5-10 times. but then It sends multiple inputs and the servo moves extra rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
socket = new java.net.Socket(inetAddress,MainActivity.wifiModulePort);
//read input msg from server
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeChars(CMD);
System.out.println(CMD);
dataOutputStream.close();

socket.close();
```

If this adds additional spaces then the simples solution would be to keep using writeutf and substring the data on the server side

socket = new java.net.Socket(inetAddress,MainActivity.wifiModulePort);

```
//read input msg from server
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(CMD);
System.out.println(CMD);
dataOutputStream.close();

socket.close();
```

and on the server side:

```
data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE).decode()
data = data[2:]
```

Quote from Javadoc:

> Writes a string to the underlying output stream using modified UTF-8
>   encoding in a machine-independent manner.
>
> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the
>   writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is
>   the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string. Following the length, each character of the string is output,
>   in sequence, using the modified UTF-8 encoding for the character. If
>   no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the
>   total number of bytes written to the output stream. This will be at
>   least two plus the length of str, and at most two plus thrice the
>   length of str.

Comment: Great! As far as I understand it is now able to receive the whole string with some noise in the beginning, right? We are close to the solution

Comment: FINALLLYYYY!!!!!  IT WORKS ..I tried writeChars() it didnt work but writeutf() at the client and data[:2] at the server worked well for me, It takes the input properly (yes the null values are there SILL!) ....although i dont think this is efficient when it comes to Networking, but it works like a charm!!.. You are awesome man..Ping me @socialsubscriptionss@gmail.com.

Comment: Yahoo! Yes of course, improvements may be applied, but the goal was to propose the solution by changing only couple lines of the initial code. The best would be using select () on the server side and use for each in socket instead of the second infinite loop. Great to hear that it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Please can you provide you Android code snippet (where you are sending the message) to the server.

When I run the code on my local machine (I don't have a raspberry controller so I commented out certain lines):

```
import sys
import socket
import select

ctrCmd = ['Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right', 'Stop', 'Connect']

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)

tcpSerSock.listen(1)
print('Waiting for connection')

sendInterval = 1.0  # interval(sec) for sending messages to connected clients

rxset = [tcpSerSock]
txset = []
while True:
    print("Waiting for connection")
    tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print("...connected from :", addr)

    try:
        while True:
            data = ''
            data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE).decode()
            print("This", data)

            if not data:
                print("No Data", data)
                break
            if data == ctrCmd[0]:
                print("I am here")
                # Servomotor.ServoUp()
                print("Increase: ")
                #tcpCliSock.send("Servo Increases".encode())
            if data == ctrCmd[1]:
                # Servomotor.ServoDown()
                print("Decrease: ")
                #tcpCliSock.send("Servo Decreases".encode())
            if data == ctrCmd[2]:
                # Servomotor.ledOn()
                print("Led On")
                #tcpCliSock.send("Led On".encode())
            if data == ctrCmd[3]:
                # Servomotor.ledOff()
                print("Led Off")
               # tcpCliSock.send("Led Off".encode())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Servomotor.close()
        # GPIO.cleanup()
        print('Exception')
tcpSerSock.close()
```

And on the client side a run the following code:

```
import sys
import socket
import time

ctrCmd = [b'Up', b'Down', b'Left', b'Right', b'Stop', b'Connect']

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
time.sleep(1)
for i in range(len(ctrCmd)):
    tcpCliSock.send(ctrCmd[i])
    time.sleep(1)
data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
print(data)
tcpCliSock.close()
```

What I finally receive is :

```
Waiting for connection
Waiting for connection
...connected from : ('127.0.0.1', 54430)
This Up
I am here
Increase:
This Down
Decrease:
This Left
Led On
This Right
Led Off
This Stop
This Connect
```

As you may have noticed the key is that on the client side instead of sending string I am sending a byte array (b'Up', instead of 'Up'). So as you see there is no problem on the server side.

Probably on your Android side yo will need something like:

```
String msg = "Up"
byte[] byteArr = msg.getBytes();
```

**Update**

Ok, I think I see what's happening there. Using the Socket's output stream you can only send byte data. And what it actually does is converting your message to an array of bytes (CMD.getBytes()). Not surprisingly your server is receiving everything step by step, byte by byte.
What you need to do is:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //UI Element
    Button btnUp;
    Button btnDown;
    Button btnLedOn;
    Button btnLedOff;
    EditText txtAddress;
    /*TextView message;*/
    Socket myAppSocket = null;
    public static String wifiModuleIp = "";
    public static int wifiModulePort = 0;
    public static String CMD = "0";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        btnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        btnLedOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLedOn);
        btnLedOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLedOff);
        txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress);
        /*message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);*/

        btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();
                CMD = "Up";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });
        btnDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();
                CMD = "Down";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_increase_servo = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_increase_servo.execute();
            }
        });
        btnLedOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();;
                CMD = "ON";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_led_on = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_led_on.execute();
            }
        });
        btnLedOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getIPandPort();
                CMD = "OFF";
                Socket_AsyncTask cmd_led_off = new Socket_AsyncTask();
                cmd_led_off.execute();
            }
        });

    }
    public void getIPandPort()
    {
        String iPandPort = txtAddress.getText().toString();

        Log.d("MYTEST","IP String: "+ iPandPort);
        String temp[]= iPandPort.split(":");
        wifiModuleIp = temp[0];
        wifiModulePort = Integer.valueOf(temp[1]);
        Log.d("MY TEST","IP:" +wifiModuleIp);
        Log.d("MY TEST","PORT:"+wifiModulePort);
    }
    public class Socket_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        Socket socket;
        OutputStreamWriter osw;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{

                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.wifiModuleIp);
                socket = new java.net.Socket(inetAddress,MainActivity.wifiModulePort);
                //read input msg from server
                osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), 'UTF-8');
                osw.write(CMD, 0, CMD.length());
                out.flush();
                socket.close();
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace();}catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: increasing the buffer doesn't do any thing instead it increased the number of clicks on Up button  on my App. also yes to your answer but how do I remove the space after my data? Any help with that?

Comment: I did what you said but it gives the same output this time shows "No Data b' ' "

Comment: without decode() it gives a data output as -> b'U' then b'p' on next line and the finally b'', and after a few presses of the Up button it gives b'Up' which doesnt work as my ctrCmd doesnt have b'Up' it only has 'Up' thats why I used Decode to get rid of that 'b'

Comment: Have a look on the updated answer. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: do I copy paste this in my app's try { } block?
I copy pasted and found that my python doesn't receive data now it gives No data, I tried changing the python code but no success.

Comment: Your server is actually correct, so there is nothing to change there. What you actually do is converting your string to bytes. When you call dataOutputStream.writeBytes(CMD) is actually dataoutputstrem.write(CMD.getBytes()). So as you see you are sending an array of bytes. That is the reason of such a weird behavior: instead of sending a whole string, your client sends an array and your server gets everything byte by byte.

Comment: so how do i send the whole string? I really need help, please if you can fix it. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tested the code I have put in the answer? Still the same error?

Comment: yes i did try that, Now Python doesn't receive the data only a blank space (I guess) because the output on python console says "This " which before the changes it said This U
This p
This  
on separate lines

Comment: I have posted another answer, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

`if not "some string"` won't be equal to True.
You might want to change it to:

```
if data != "" :
    # process here
    pass
```

You received data in separate line, it might be because of sending separately.
you can look at my code that i once written for TCP socket.
[TCP Socket](https://github.com/mohammadrezza/pure-socket-server-and-client)

Also `ctrCmd[0]` is equal to `'Up'` and your data content as i see in shell are characters like `'U'` and `'P'`. So the line

```
if data == ctrCmd[0]:
    print("I am here")
```

won't run, because `'Up'` is not equal to `'U'`.

Comment: this doesn't do much of a difference i am not facing the problems with the if loop, My main issue is the data sending separately, I have a console output in my android app which confirms that the data i am sending is being sent all together at once. The receiver(Python uses TCP) so that recieves the data separately, I need a way to receive the data alltogether in one buffer, I need its code ive looked up everywhere no one suggests a clear implication of how to use a buffer in RPI Sockets with Android.

Comment: have you tried debugging the data content? is there any '\n' in it ?

Comment: Yes i checked for the \n, and the data i send is "Up" from Android but the Python using TCP receives data as separate thats what this question is about, you can check the update where Ive put the Image of my output.